# in R, change dataframe column from the first occurence of a second column

Tags: r, dataframe, find-occurrences

I have a dataframe that is similar to this:

```
set.seed(1004)
x <- c(sort(rnorm(40)),sort(rnorm(20)),
       sort(rnorm(40)),sort(rnorm(20)))
x[30:40] <- -x[30:40]+1
x[90:100] <- -x[90:100]+1

y <- c(rep('a',times = 60),rep('b',times = 60))
z <- 1:length(x)

df <- data.frame(z, x, y)
```

I would like to make a new column according to `x` and `y`. What I want is that in every `y` subgroup (i.e. 'a' and 'b' in the example), the first occurence where `x > 0`, the next rows for this extra column should have the same value (factor). And this, even though `x < 0` again after this first occurrence.

In the end I want something like:

```
df$y2 <- c(rep('0', times = 20), rep('1', times = 40), rep('0', times = 19), rep('1', times = 41))
```

So far I tried this:

```
library(magrittr)
df %<>% 
  mutate(y2 = case_when(
    x < 0 ~ '0',
    x >= 0 ~ '1'
  ))
```

But I am missing an argument so that `y2` stays at '1' even though `x` becomes negative again.

A graphical representation of what I want is: so far I have this :

[image]

While I want this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(z, x, y)
df$y2 <- c(rep('0', times = 20), rep('1', times = 40), rep('0', times = 19), rep('1', times = 41))

library(magrittr)
df %<>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  mutate(y3 = cummax(ifelse(x < 0, 0, 1))) #by taking cummax, y3 will always be 1 after the first x > 0 for each group y

table(df$y2 == df$y3, useNA = "always")

TRUE <NA> 
 120    0
```

Comment: Or `cummax(x >= 0)`

Comment: oh yeah you are right I don't even need the `ifelse()`

Comment: Thank you, as I does answer my question for this reproducible example, I accept this answer. But for some reason it doesn't work on my original dataset (no warning messages, just that all the `y3` equal 1).

I'll try to fix it, but thank you for the `cummax` function.

Comment: oh I got the problem, `group_by()` should contain 2 columns in my case, not just one.

Comment: I have an extra question : how can I make sure that y3 = 0 before the transition even though x > 0 ? For instance, if the first x of my subgroup is superior to 0, this code is making y3 = 1 for the entire subgroup. But I don't want that

Comment: Could you ask a new question for this other problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here i'm using the function Position to find the position of the first occurrence that fulfills a certain criteria. In this case x > 0.
Then I create a vector with the values for the new column based on this position.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

createNewValues <- function(x){
  splitPoint <- Position(function(x) x>0, x)
  return(rep(c(0, 1), times = c(splitPoint-1, length(x)-splitPoint+1)))
}

df %<>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  mutate(y2 = createNewValues(x))
```